# c# xml file contain Repeating nodes are skipped and not saved into DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datatable, dataset

Hello i am trying to read and save an XML file into DataSet and the problem is the Repeating nodes are skipped and not saved into DataSet

below is the xml:

```
<Production>
<Number>399195</Number>
<Code>21</Code>
<VehicleID>VR7A45GYVNL012461</VehicleID>
<ModelID>1CCE</ModelID>
<Date>2022-05-10T01:12:05.000Z</Date>
<ProductionSpecificationText>CDNB08 </ProductionSpecificationText>
<ProductionSpecificationText>CDPK02 </ProductionSpecificationText>
<ProductionSpecificationText>CDNM00 </ProductionSpecificationText>
<ProductionSpecificationText>CB0DSY </ProductionSpecificationText>
<ProductionSpecificationText>CDRL02 </ProductionSpecificationText>
<ProductionSpecificationText>CDL700 </ProductionSpecificationText>
<ProductionSpecificationText>CB0CCE </ProductionSpecificationText>
</Production>


DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    
dataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\elhammh\Desktop\xmlfiletest");
```

Comment: Check you dataset and see how many tables you have.  The Dataset ReadXml created fragmented tables that cannot be used.  Better to read file using XML Linq.  Will post code.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication23
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("VehicleID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ModelID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductionSpecificationText", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement production = doc.Root;

            int number = (int)production.Element("Number");
            int code = (int)production.Element("Code");
            string vehicleId = (string)production.Element("VehicleID");
            string modelId = (string)production.Element("ModelID");
            DateTime date = (DateTime)production.Element("Date");
            foreach (XElement text in production.Elements("ProductionSpecificationText"))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    number,
                    code,
                    vehicleId,
                    modelId,
                    date,
                    (string)text
                });
            }

 

        }
    }
 
}
```